# Generate a Secure Random Integer in Range with PHP 5.6

Tags: php, security, random, entropy

I would like to generate a secure random integer between `$min` and `$max` in PHP5.6. Both `rand()` and `mt_rand()` in PHP are considered not to be Cryptographically-Secure.

From the [docs](https://secure.php.net/rand):

> **Caution**
>
> This function does not generate cryptographically secure values, and should not be used for cryptographic purposes. If you need a cryptographically secure value, consider using random_int(), random_bytes(), or openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() instead.

PHP 7 adds `random_int()` ([docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php)), which fits my use-case perfectly:

> random_int — Generates cryptographically secure pseudo-random integers

But how can this functionality be attained in PHP 5.6?

My naive attempt was this:

```
<?php
function secure_rand($min, $max)
{
    return (unpack("N", openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(4)) % ($max - $min)) + $min;
}
```

But I seem to always get "2" when calling `secure_rand(1, 100)`. I have also read that using a modulus operation in this way can create a bias. How can I emulate `random_int()` in PHP 5.6?

Comment: https://github.com/ircmaxell/random_compat is worth looking at

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Might I introduce you to [random_compat](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat), which polyfills `random_bytes()` and `random_int()` in PHP 5 projects? (Sidenote: among other projects, it's being picked up by Wordpress in 4.4.)

```
function secure_rand($min, $max)
{
    return (unpack("N", openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(4)) % ($max - $min)) + $min;
}
```

Even if this was doing what you wanted it to do, this is a [biased random number generator](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/07/how-safely-generate-random-strings-and-integers-in-php#biased-csprng) when `($max - $min)` is not an even power of 2.

Comment: Thanks Scott! I think this is the answer; I've reviewed random_compat and this is exactly what I'm looking for. PHP7's `random_int()` is what I want, and this seems like the next best thing.

Answer (score 2):

Found a pretty well working solution. In the example the mcrypt extension is used, but it also works with `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` if you need more information look [here](https://codeascraft.com/2012/07/19/better-random-numbers-in-php-using-devurandom/).

```
function secure_rand( $min, $max ) {
    $diff = $max - $min;
    if ($diff < 0 || $diff > 0x7FFFFFFF) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Bad range");
    }
    $bytes = mcrypt_create_iv( 4, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM );

    // if mcrypt is not enabled on your server, you can use this
    //$bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes( 4 );

    // if mbstring is not enabled, you can also use iconv_strlen
    if ($bytes === false || mb_strlen($bytes, '8bit') != 4) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to get 4 bytes");
    }

    $ary = unpack("Nint", $bytes);
    $val = $ary['int'] & 0x7FFFFFFF;   // 32-bit safe
    $fp = $val / 2147483647.0; // convert to [0,1]
    // if you really need a type of int take this
    // return (int) round($fp * $diff) + $min;
    // otherwise it will return a float without decimal numbers
    return round($fp * $diff) + $min;
}

var_dump( secure_rand( 1, 1000 ) );
var_dump( secure_rand( 1, 20 ) );
var_dump( secure_rand( 1, 10 ) );
var_dump( secure_rand( 1, 5000 ) );
var_dump( secure_rand( 1, 1111111 ) );
```

**Updated:** comments in source, removed cast to float/int, used `mb_strlen()` instead of `strlen()`

Comment: Converting to float might lose precision (leading to biases) or leak data (int<->float conversion is not constant-time IIRC), and `strlen()` falls prey to `mbstring.func_overload`.

Comment: @ScottArciszewski: updated, by the way, feel free to edit my answer

Comment: Thanks! I've ended up going with [random_compat](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat), but this looks like a good option as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **openssl_random_pseudo_bytes**, as it is available since PHP 5.3

> Generates a string of pseudo-random bytes, with the number of bytes determined by the length parameter.
>
> It also indicates if a cryptographically strong algorithm was used to produce the pseudo-random bytes, and does this via the optional crypto_strong parameter. It's rare for this to be FALSE, but some systems may be broken or old.

Read more at [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php)

Comment: Right, but that's bytes, and I need a random integer within a range while maintaining a full range of entropy.

Comment: Okay, just see the first example and use bindec to transform to dec and you are almost done.